# Number of ways we can partition a set into two subsets such that the GCD of product of the elements in both subsets is minimum

Tags: python, algorithm, subset, dynamic-programming, greatest-common-divisor

We have a set or a unique list of positive integers with constraints that the size of the list or set can go up to 10000. The objective is to divide the list into 2 non-empty subsets such that the GCD(Prod1, Prod2) == 1, where Prod1 is the product of all the elements in subset 1 and Prod2 is the product of all the elements in subset 2.

For e.g.

Input:

```
5 1 2
```

Output:

```
6
```

6 subsets that satisfy the condition

```
{1}, {2, 5} = gcd(1, 10) = 1
{1, 2}, {5} = gcd(2, 5) = 1
{1, 5}, {2} = gcd(5, 2) = 1
{2, 5}, {1} = gcd(10, 1) = 1
{5}, {1, 2} = gcd(5, 2) = 1
{2}, {1, 5} = gcd(2, 5) = 1
```

Input:

```
2 3 6
```

Output:

```
0
```

As there are no subsets that satisfy the condition

I tried brute force approach by generating all 2-way partitionings and finding its products, then taking its gcd. but obviously, this takes at least O(N^2) or more and so much memory which is not feasible considering the constraints. Is there any better approach using Dynamic Programming just like in subset-sum/difference question or using any other algorithm/data structure?

Comment: Create a prime factorization for each number. For each partitioning each prime number (with power of at least 1) can then only be present in one of the products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael Butscher observes, every two positive integers that are not relatively prime must be on the same side of the partition. This turns out to be a sufficient as well as necessary condition.

Make a graph whose vertices are the given positive integers and whose edges indicate pairs of integers that are not relatively prime. Count the number of connected components k in this graph. Return 2<sup>k</sup> − 2 since independently, each component can be on the left side of the partition or the right, minus the 2 degenerate partitions where every component is on the same side.